# Multiplication between two text fields - Android Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to Android and programming and having a bit of difficulties with my code. I tried to research this but couldn't find out what was wrong, would appreciate the help. I am basically trying to multiply two values but every time I run my emulator and click on the button (calculate) it crashes:

**Java Code:**

```
 package com.example.cantcook;

 import java.math.BigDecimal;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calculator extends Activity {
    EditText costofmeal, amountofpeople;
    TextView costperperson;
    Button Calculate;
    BigDecimal costNum, percentNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

        costofmeal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
        amountofpeople = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        Calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        costperperson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //costperperson.setText("£0.00");


        Calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

        public void onClick (View v)
        {
            costNum = new BigDecimal(costofmeal.getText().toString());
            percentNum = new BigDecimal(amountofpeople.getText().toString());
            costperperson.setText(costNum.multiply(percentNum).toString());
        }
        });
    }
```

**XML code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".Calculator" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="£"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:text="  Total spent on Shopping"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="  Amount of People"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:onClick="Btncalculate"
        android:text="Calculate" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="£" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please show the logcat output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml layout you have `android:onClick="Btncalculate"` in button1. What this does is when a click happens Android tries to look for Btncalculate method in your activity. And I'm assuming you don't have it there, since you're using an OnClickListener for button1(which, in my opinion, is better then using android:onClick).

Remove `android:onClick="Btncalculate"` from the xml file and it should work(unless there are other errors, in which case it would be great to see the stack trace).

**Update**

From your stacktrace:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: £5

Looks like you're code is trying to put "£5" into BigDecimal, which is not allowed, since it is not a number. To fix this you can either set `android:inputType` to a number in your `editText1` and remove `android:text="£"`, or use a separate method to filter out the `£` sign from input.

Comment: I deleted the onClick and it still crashes when the emulator runs (i was following a youtube tutorial and forgot to delete it) do you mean the "LogCat" if so here it is http://pastebin.com/LGsYBxCi sorry if its an easy question im new to this

Comment: thanks for the help :-D it worked!!! out of curiosity how would i let the user enter decimal into android:id="@+id/editText1" (because its the total shopping amount)

Comment: You can find a full list of available android:inputType values here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html what you're looking for is probably TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL